# Select SQL Search String Based on Content of ASP.NET Text Field

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

The goal of the code-behind below is to select a SQL `SELECT` statement in a string variable based on whether or not a text box is or is not null, then execute the statement. I've tried both using a variable and directly executing the `SELECT` statement using

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = 'SELECT...'
```

Unfortunately, neither method is returning anything at all when I put data in the text fields to be checked.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;

namespace MyProgram
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
       string query = "";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = query;
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("NameLast", SearchLast.ToString());
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("NameFirst", SearchFirst.ToString());
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("SSN", SearchSSN.ToString());
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("DOB", SearchDOB.ToString());
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("Case", SearchCase.ToString());

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                if (SearchCase.Text != string.Empty)
                {
                    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT CLTCAS,CLTLST+', '+CLTFST,DATEFROMPARTS(cltbyr,cltbmm,cltbdd),CLTCTY+', '+[ CLTSTA],CLTSSN,CLTSEX FROM CLTMST WHERE CLTCAS = @Case";
                }
                if (SearchSSN.Text != string.Empty && SearchSSN.Text.Length == 4 && SearchLast.Text == string.Empty && SearchFirst.Text == string.Empty)
                {
                    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT CLTCAS,CLTLST+', '+CLTFST,DATEFROMPARTS(cltbyr,cltbmm,cltbdd),CLTCTY+', '+[ CLTSTA],CLTSSN,CLTSEX FROM CLTMST WHERE right(CLTSSN,4) = @SSN";
                }
                if (SearchSSN.Text != string.Empty && SearchSSN.Text.Length == 9 && SearchLast.Text != string.Empty && SearchFirst.Text == string.Empty)
                {
                    query = "SELECT CLTCAS,CLTLST+', '+CLTFST,DATEFROMPARTS(cltbyr,cltbmm,cltbdd),CLTCTY+', '+[ CLTSTA],CLTSSN,CLTSEX FROM CLTMST WHERE CLTSSN = @SSN";
                }
                if (SearchLast.Text != string.Empty && SearchFirst.Text != string.Empty && SearchDOB.Text == string.Empty && SearchSSN.Text == string.Empty)
                {
                    query = "SELECT CLTCAS,CLTLST+', '+CLTFST,DATEFROMPARTS(cltbyr,cltbmm,cltbdd),CLTCTY+', '+[ CLTSTA],CLTSSN,CLTSEX FROM CLTMST WHERE CLTLST = @NameLast and CLTFST like @NameFirst+'%'";
                }
                if (SearchLast.Text != string.Empty && SearchFirst.Text == string.Empty && SearchSSN.Text == string.Empty && SearchDOB.Text == string.Empty)
                {
                    query = "SELECT CLTCAS,CLTLST+', '+CLTFST,DATEFROMPARTS(cltbyr,cltbmm,cltbdd),CLTCTY+', '+[ CLTSTA],CLTSSN,CLTSEX FROM CLTMST WHERE CLTLST = @NameLast+'%'";
                }
                if (SearchLast.Text == string.Empty && SearchFirst.Text == string.Empty && SearchSSN.Text == string.Empty && SearchDOB.Text != string.Empty)
                {
                    query = "SELECT CLTCAS,CLTLST+', '+CLTFST,DATEFROMPARTS(cltbyr,cltbmm,cltbdd),CLTCTY+', '+[ CLTSTA],CLTSSN,CLTSEX FROM CLTMST WHERE (cltbyr+'-'+cltbmm+'-'+cltbdd = @DOB)";
                }
                if (SearchLast.Text != string.Empty && SearchFirst.Text == string.Empty && SearchSSN.Text == string.Empty && SearchDOB.Text != string.Empty)
                {
                    query = "SELECT CLTCAS,CLTLST+', '+CLTFST,DATEFROMPARTS(cltbyr,cltbmm,cltbdd),CLTCTY+', '+[ CLTSTA],CLTSSN,CLTSEX FROM CLTMST WHERE CLTLST = @NameLast+'%' AND (cltbyr+'-'+cltbmm+'-'+cltbdd = @DOB)";
                }
        }

        protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think we need to execute the command.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger? It appears that, for instance, `SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("NameLast", SearchLast.ToString());` is going to add the name of the TYPE (ie Textbox) into the param, not the text value of the textbox.

Comment: Looks like unstructured mess to me. You need to start with building select and then create command, and execute

Comment: @marc_s Not according to the MSDN. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @asawyer: ah - sorry - I was thinking about the `SelectCommand` on a `SqlDataAdapter` (not a `SqlDataSource`).

Comment: @marc_s I thought so as well for a bit, but realized that OP didn't say there was a compiler error, so checked. It's clear though that OP is having trouble with a basic understanding of the asp.net page lifecycle, and should [review this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) as well as not realizing that calling `ToString` on a regular type is not going to give him the textbox value he wants.

Comment: Is it a problem with (1) what's coming back being captured (a C# problem), or (2) a problem with SQL code, or (3) a problem with submitting the query to SQL?  To answer (2) & (3), start simply & build up.  For example, (a) hardcode a query, like `string query = "SELECT TOP 1... FROM CLTMST"` (no `WHERE` clause, and `SelectParameters.Add` lines commented out).  Then, (b) run a trace in SQL Server Profiler while the page loads, to see if SQL Server is even seeing/executing any query.  (c) Copying the query out of Profiler, into Mgmt Studio, you can see if the query works, & rows/cols returned.

Comment: Just curious, did either of the posted answers solve your problem, or help you out?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off doing this declaratively, with ControlParameters.  In your markup, you would have a `<SelectParameters>` section to your SqlDataSource1 declaration:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runate="server"
    CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False" ...other stuff... >
    ...other stuff...
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter name="NameLast" controlid="SearchLast" propertyname="Text"/>
        <asp:ControlParameter name="NameFirst" controlid="SearchFirst" propertyname="Text"/>
        <asp:ControlParameter name="SSN" controlid="SearchSSN" propertyname="Text"/>
        <asp:ControlParameter name="DOB" controlid="SearchDOB" propertyname="Text"/>
        <asp:ControlParameter name="Case" controlid="SearchCase" propertyname="Text"/>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This way you don't have to deal with adding them on Page_Load.  Notice that I added the `CancelSelectOnNullParameter` property, and set it to false.  That way your query will execute, even if some of the values are empty.

You could also combine all your queries into one, that way you don't need to have all those if statements in your click event:

```
SELECT 
    CLTCAS, 
    CLTLST+', '+CLTFST,
    DATEFROMPARTS(cltbyr,cltbmm,cltbdd), 
    CLTCTY+', '+[ CLTSTA],
    CLTSSN,
    CLTSEX 
FROM CLTMST 
WHERE 
    CLTCAS = @Case
    OR right(CLTSSN,4) = @SSN
    OR CLTSSN = @SSN
    OR (CLTLST = @NameLast AND CLTFST LIKE @NameFirst+'%')
    OR CLTLST LIKE @NameLast+'%'
    OR cltbyr+'-'+cltbmm+'-'+cltbdd = @DOB
    OR (CLTLST LIKE @NameLast+'%' AND (cltbyr+'-'+cltbmm+'-'+cltbdd = @DOB))
```

---

As far as your original code goes, when you add TextBox values as parameters, you want to add the `.Text` property as the default value:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("NameLast", SearchLast.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this

In the class scope

```
private bool _hasWhere;
```

Method to dynamically build Select statement

```
private string GetSelectSql()
{

    string sql = "Select ...... From .... "; // also, make sql a StringBuilder

    if (txtLastName.Text.Trim() != string.empty)
    {
        if (SetWhere()) 
            sql += " Where ";
        else 
           sql += ",";  
        sql += string.Format(" LastName like '%{0}%' ", txtLastName);
    }

    if (txtFirstName.Text.Trim() != string.empty)
    {
        if (SetWhere()) 
           sql += " Where ";
        else 
           sql += ",";  
        sql += string.Format(" FirstName like '%{0}%' ", txtLastName);
    }
    // keep on going here .................

    return sql;
}
```

Helper method to identify if `where` was inserted already

```
// if your sql was StringBuilder you would just pass it here and do sb.Append(" Where ")
private bool SetWhere()
{
    if (!hasWhere) 
    {
       hasWhere = true;
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

A method that gets you the command object

```
private SqlCommand CreateCommand (string sql)
{

    .............
    SqlCommand command = new Sqlcommand(sql,....
    .............
    return Command
 }
```

So then you can assign your command right before executing it

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = CreateCommand(GetSelectSql())
```

This is not fully functional code but I hope this will give you an idea what you need to do